# Quantal (12.10) Gnome 3.7.1: User Shell extension not enabled

Tags: gnome, 12.10, gnome-tweak-tool

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 from the previous version.

I have Gnome 3.7.1 (according to Synaptic packet manager) and Tweak Tools. I can't get User <strike>Shell</strike> *Theme* Extension enabled in Tweak Tools -- there's an exclamation mark next to that switch. Can somebody help me out?  I've been to **https://extensions.gnome.org/** but the only User Theme extension is given as "Outdated". I've downloaded two themes from gnome-looks.org and placed them in `~/.themes`. If I right-click anywhere, the menu that opens up, looks quite primitive. What can I do to fix the problem?

[user shell extension not enabled gnome 3.7.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuxML.jpg)

[right click menu looks strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA2Es.jpg)

Comment: "What can I do next?". Wait for the extension to be compatible with Gnome 3.7.1 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the testing release of gnome3 (ppa:ricotz/testing) which will generally not be compatible with extensions.  In order to downgrade to gnome 3.6, you will have to purge the ricotz/testing ppa with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ricotz/testing`.  Then you will have to reinstall gnome shell from the standard gnome3 repository (ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3).  Note that at the moment, the content of these two repositories is roughly the same as gnome 3.6 came out less than a month ago.

Comment: Does user shell extension work with gnome 3.6?

Comment: If you mean the user theme extension, then yes.

Comment: By the way, I get `ppa-purge: command not found` from Terminal, if I give that command.

Comment: Then you should probably install ppa-purge...`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Answer (score 0):

When using ppa:ricotz/testing you are suppose to use the provided gnome-shell-extensions package which contains the official extensions compatible with the latest upstream (dev-)releases.
Also remove the manually installed extensions which collide with them in the package to make sure you are actually using the compatible ones.

Comment: I would explain how WobbyWindows gets the provided gnome-shell-extensions.                                                        It might help as well if you can detail how you can remove the manually installed extensions